# The Collation specified by SQL Server is not supported

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, collation

We have huge problem with SQL Server Collation.

Our application database is using

```
Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

But our client created their databases with

```
Georgian_Modern_Set_CI_AS
```

We are using entityframework and we cannot run application on client server.We cannot run query but when we edit table we can see table data.

When we send query the error returns

```
The Collation specified by SQL Server is not supported
```

Change the collation is very difficult thing so i don't try that. Is there any way to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the database collation or the instance collation is difficult to change?  You need to specify the collation for your database, and it can be different than the server collation.  You may want to set partial database containment to take advantage of contained database collations. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-database-collations

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft We tried to 'Collate' column when table create one by one looks fine but when we want connect data from Entity Framework. We cannot get a result... 'The Collation specified by SQL Server is not supported' error returned again and again